# In an SSRS report builder expression, I am trying to get the sum of a conditional count

Tags: sum, report, expression, builder

I want the sum of a count IF the count is >=3.  This gives me a sum of all the counts, regardless if they are <> 3:

=Sum(Iif(CountDistinct(Fields!ENCOUNTER.Value)>=3,1,0))

This produces th same result, the total number of distinct encounters:

=Sum(Iif(CountDistinct(Fields!ENCOUNTER.Value)>=3,CountDistinct(Fields!ENCOUNTER.Value),Nothing))

I want the total number of distinct encounters if there are 3 or more per person.  I am grouping on person first, then encounter id.

Ex:
Person        Enc
John            1
Bob             4
Sue             2
Ann             3

Total Enc>=3:  2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, if there are not details rows under ENCOUNTER, you should directly compare the Fields!ENCOUNTER.Value instead of using countdistinct()

Sum(IIF(Fields!ENCOUNTER.value>=3,1,0))

If you have multiple detail rows under ENCOUNTER group level, your requirement can't be achieved because we can't use an aggregation function within an aggregation function. Which means we can't get the distinct ENCOUNTER IDs first, then calculate the total.

Comment: There are multiple detail rows under the Encounter group, so sum of encounter value doesn't work.  I need to know the number of encounters by a person, but only if the number >= 3. I need a workaround, maybe a SQL solution?

Comment: I found a workaround.  I created another query that selects only those people with 3 or more encounters and added it to the report as a subreport.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I created another query that selects only those people with 3 or more encounters and added it to the report as a subreport